# Angular-Chart drilldown options in doughnut chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, drilldown, angular-chartist.js

When each segment is clicked,need to form a another chart with its  respectively lower level of a data.

This [experience](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown) need in Angular-chart.js

Comment: sridar did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no support for that with [`angular-chart.js`](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js), you have to implement it by yourself.

Also angular-chart is getting inherited from chart.js, there is already asked question

See [`Any support drill-down charts?`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3115#event-792845174)